# Oracle - Merge into, commit after n-rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge

I know how to commit a simple **UPDATE** statement after n-rows.

How to implement that with a **MERGE INTO** statement, say commit after each 10000 rows:

```
MERGE INTO incident a
USING 
(
select b.incident_sk incident_sk_bkp , b.mapping_id mapping_id_bkp 
from incident a
join  incident_bkp b
on a.incident_sk=b.incident_sk
where 1=1
and a.mapping_id <> b.mapping_id_bkp
) b ON (a.mapping_id = b.mapping_id_bkp)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET a.mapping_id = b.mapping_id_bkp;
```

Additional question: is that necessary for 1,2 million records on some decent hardware?

Comment: [Tom Kyte on issueing frequent commits](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022). Are you doing this because you've read somewhere that it's a good idea, or because your DB's undo/redo isn't sized properly and you get errors doing it in one go?

Comment: It is not necessary (and widely considered a poor practice).

Comment: In that past I encountered problems when updating large datasets without committing a subset of them in the process. The deployment process in my working environment is critical, every additional delivery influences our SLA in a negative way. Therefore I want to prevent possible issues beforehand.

Comment: Splitting up the update (or merge) introduces the potential for data integrity issues, or at least restart issues. Isn't it better for the entire update to fail and roll back, rather than part of it committing? You can end up with a mix of old and new data, and then have to work out how to back out or pick up where you left off.

Comment: What problems did you encounter?  If the issue is that you have applications that are updating the same rows that you are trying to merge data into, that's a very different problem than if you're running on a system which somehow isn't sized to deal with 1.2 million row updates (which should be pretty trivial these days).

Comment: I guess if you absolutely had to, you could add a parameter range to the `using` clause and build a loop that calls it with incrementing values. But I agree with the other comments, that will just make it slower and more resource intensive for no great benefit, and if your database can't update 2 million rows in one shot then you probably need a bigger laptop. If you are worried about a runtime error triggering a long rollback, you might look at [DML Error Logging](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables004.htm).

Comment: "In that past I encountered problems when updating large datasets without committing a subset of them". How many poor design decisions are taken because sometime in the past somebody followed good practice and there was a problem (usually unrelated to doing the right thing) ? Too often.